# Setting ComboBox.SelectedItem at bind time?

Tags: wpf

I have a ComboBox in a DataTemplate which is being selected by a cell template selector in a DataGrid.

How do I set the SelectedItem to zero when the ComboBox is bound to its ItemsSource?  There's often just one item and I want it to appear immediately instead of having to be selected by the user.

My DataGrid column looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty Avl">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
    <selectors:PartAvailableSelector StrTemplate="{StaticResource PartAvailableAtStrTemplate}">
      <selectors:PartAvailableSelector.NetTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AltLocations}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    SelectedItem="0"
                    />
        </DataTemplate>
      </selectors:PartAvailableSelector.NetTemplate>
    </selectors:PartAvailableSelector>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My selector has DataTemplate properties, just because it's easier.  I inlined the NetTemplate template for this post.  I normally have it in my window resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedItem` will the hold entire object from `ItemsSource`, to set the 0 item as selected you need to set `SelectedIndex="0"` or in ViewModel u need to bind  `SelectedItem="{Binding SLocation}"` to `AltLocations[0]`

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AltLocations}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedIndex="0"
                />
```

Or

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AltLocations}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SLocation}"
                />
```

Vm

```
private Location sLocation
   public Location SLocation
    {
        get { return sLocation; }
        set
        {
            sLocation= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SLocation"));
        }
    }
```

//Ctor

`SLocation=AltLocations[0];`